# Why does the CO2 gas quantity in Sodastream cartridges differ in different nations?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, gas-laws

Just was looking at the $\ce{CO2}$ cartridge for the Sodastream soda / seltzer maker I was planning on buying and this bit of info caught my eye:
Any idea why they may want to pack $\pu{25 g}$ less $\ce{CO2}$ for South Africa? Is it some regulatory issue? Marketing gimmick? 
Or more interestingly, some technical factor?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Without doing much more research, I would assume that temperature plays a big role here. The maximum temperatures in South Africa tend to be a bit hotter than in the habitable places in Australia.

Comment: Hardly a chemistry question

Comment: @Martin-マーチン On the other hand, I’m sure the habitable places in South Africa are also colder than the hottest temperatures in Australia.